# Accessing default values of functions

Tags: ecmascript-6

In this code, `divisor` has a default of `100`. It is also set to `100` if the value parses to 1 or less.

```
class Rounder {
    constructor(divisor = 100) {
        let value = parseInt(divisor);
        this.divisor = (value <= 1)? 100: value;
    }
}
```

Other than using something like `const ROUNDER_DIVISOR_DEFAULT = 100;` somewhere, is there a way to retrieve the default `100`, so that the literal value doesn't need to be repeated?

Comment: nope, there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Derlin's comment. I'd just revise the function so that the literal is needed only once:

```
class Rounder {
    constructor(divisor) {
        let value = parseInt(divisor);
        this.divisor = (value > 1)? value: 100;
    }
}
```

This will work for valid and invalid inputs, i.e. those that parse to `NaN`.

I know this doesn't answer your question specifically, but it does get around the problem of messing up your code with multiple copies of literals, or infrequently used constants.